# In the local case, cookies are shared between the backend front ends and the login is maintained, but after deployment, the login is not maintained

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am changing the settings in various ways
It's failing

back/index.js

```
if (prod) {
    app.use(hpp());
    app.use(helmet());
    app.use(morgan('combined'));
    app.use(cors({
        origin: /api.nodebird\.com$/,
        credentials: true,
    }));
} else {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(cors({
        origin: true,
        credentials: true,
    }));
}
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET));
app.use(expressSession({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false, // https를 쓸 때 true
        domain: prod && '.terecal-nodebird.com',
        // domain: prod && '.terecal-nodebird.com',
    },
    name: 'rnbck',
}));
```

front/server.js

```
    server.use(expressSession({
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        // secret: '',
        secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
        },
    }));
```

Why does it work fine on my local server but not on Amazon servers?

And in local environment, if I request to localhost: 3060, login is maintained, but at 127.0.0.1:3060, login is not maintained

Maybe it has something to do with this?

If you know, please let me know Thank you

Comment: In production, in which domains do the backend server and frontend server lives?

Comment: back:api-terecal-notebird.com, front:terecal-nodebird.com thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are deploying to 2 different domains

1. back: api-terecal-notebird.com
2. front: terecal-nodebird.com

You (generally) can not share cookies between domains. I assume it worked on your local environment because both live in localhost, so the cookie can be shared. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)

My advice is to move your backend server to a same domain with your frontend, so they can share cookies between them.

Example:
Move the backend server to api.terecal-nodebird.com and set your cookies to have a domain of `.terecal-nodebird.com`.

OR

You can just move the backend to `terecal-nodebird.com/api`.

Comment: I need to maintain two domains because my goal is to build a front-end back-end server that uses two domains to communicate with each other. thank you

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you specifically try to do that?